# JQuery and Secondary Functions in plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern

I read this tutorial and there was a talk about secondary functions in a plugin.

How can I use those functions outside the plugin?

Comment: I think it would be better if you ask the development team of that plugin. There site should have some kind of forum to upload to, or contact to them

Answer (score 2):

With the example they gave:

```
var txt = 'Hello world!';
$.hilight.format( txt );
```