# Access jQuery Object From Plugin's Secondary Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am writing a jQuery plugin and the plugin has secondary functions (see [jQuery support](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/)). I would like to be able to loop through the elements that the jQuery object contains in order to do something to each of them. However, I cannot see how to access the original object since, in the scope of the secondary function, `this` obviously refers to the plugin object.

Is there any way to access the original elements or am I going to have to start thinking about alternative (jQuery UI -esque) techniques?

The code looks something like this:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    var
        myNewPlugin,
        mySecondaryFunction;

    mySecondaryFunction = function () {
        // the secondary function

        // `this` refers to myNewPlugin
    };

    myNewPlugin = (function () {
        var closedPrivateVariables;

        return function () {
            // the function called from the jQuery object

            return this;
        };
    }());

    myNewPlugin.mySecondaryFunction;

    $.fn.myNewPlugin = myNewPlugin;
}(jQuery));
```

**Not duplicates (questions which sound similar but are not the same)**

- [jQuery plugin: How to access elements where plugin was applied from secondary function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815802/jquery-plugin-how-to-access-elements-where-plugin-was-applied-from-secondary-fu?rq=1)
- [JQuery and Secondary Functions in plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059455/jquery-and-secondary-functions-in-plugins)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard plugin pattern is something like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
        var settings = {
            // settings
        };
        return this.each(function (i, elem) {
            //do stuff
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

To extend that for secondary functions and maintain a reference to the selected jQuery object, just capture a reference to it in the `.each()` iterator:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
        var settings = {
            // settings
        },
        self = null,
        selectedDOMElements = [],
        mySecondaryFunction = function () {
            var i = 0;
            //do more stuff
            self.css('display', 'inline-block'); //original jQuery object
            for (i = 0; i , selectedDOMElements.length; i += 1) {
                $(selectedDOMElements[i]).css('color', '#F00'); //individual child elements of the original jQuery object
            }
        };
        self = this; //store original jQuery object
        return this.each(function (i, elem) {
            selectedDOMElements.push(elem); //store individual child elements of the original jQuery object
            //do stuff
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Mix and match to do what you're looking to do.

**UPDATE:**

Try this instead:

```
(function ($) {
    var self;
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
        var settings = {
            // settings
        };
        self = this; //store original jQuery object
        return self.each(function (i, elem) {
            //do stuff
        });
    };
    $.fn.myPlugin.mySecondaryFunction = function mySecondaryFunction(options) {
        var settings = {
            // settings
        };
        return self.each(function (i, elem) { //apply to original jQuery object
            //do stuff
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

//call like this
$(selector).myPlugin();
$(selector).myPlugin.mySecondaryFunction();
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bv7PG/

Comment: I appreciate this but I don't think you quite follow. The secondary function should be callable by `$('.aSelector').myNewPlugin.mySecondaryFunction(options);` as opposed to just making a private function that the `myNewPlugin` can access when called; which, I think is what you are getting at.

Comment: I actually don't think there is any way to achieve what I am trying to do. jQuery UI doesn't allow this method of calling functions so I think that it cannot be done this way. At the minute I am just going down the jQuery UI -esque route (passing in the function to call as a string in the first param and passing in the options it accepts in the second param). `myNewPlugin` handles calling this function (pretty much what you were saying).

Comment: @pete `$(selector).myPlugin.mySecondaryFunction();` will not work without calling `$(selector).myPlugin();` first

Comment: Well that is an interesting technique and probably the closest thing you can get. Thanks a lot

Comment: +1 updated version works! JQuery also recommended to add public secondary functions as "$.fn.myPlugin.mySecondaryFunction = function(options) {}"  Ref: http://goo.gl/3EeNyW (@pete Don't have to include secondary function name in both sides)